# Graphic modification after adjusting contrast in C#

Tags: c#, image, graphics

I'm trying to create a small tool to count region of interests in a picture.

To get better results, I have to adjust the contrast of the image. When I try to do it by using a Colormatrix-System, I just get the results of the original image instead of the adjusted image.

Here is my Code. First of all I loaded an image by the following way:

```
Img = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
newBitmap = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

Afterwards I adjusted Contrast in the following way:

```
{
    domainContrast.Text = trackBar2.Value.ToString();

    contrast = 0.04f * trackBar2.Value;

    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(newBitmap.Width, newBitmap.Height);

    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
    ImageAttributes ia = new ImageAttributes();

    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[][] {
        new float[] {contrast, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f},
        new float[] {0f, contrast, 0f, 0f, 0f},
        new float[] {0f, 0f, contrast, 0f, 0f},
        new float[] {0f, 0f, 0f,  1f , 0f},
        new float[] {0.001f, 0.001f, 0.001f, 0f, 1f}
    });

    ia.SetColorMatrix(cm);
    g.DrawImage(newBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, newBitmap.Width, newBitmap.Height), 0, 0, newBitmap.Width, newBitmap.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia);

    g.Dispose();
    ia.Dispose();

    pictureBox1.Image = bm;
}
```

And here is the code for counting the rois:

```
{   
    count = 0;
    Bitmap nB = new Bitmap(newBitmap.Width, newBitmap.Height);
    int lastCol = 1;
    //int y =250;

    int countStart = 1;
    int countEnd = 1;

    Here is the code of the routine:

        for (int y = 1; y < newBitmap.Height - 1; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 1; x < newBitmap.Width - 1; x++)
            {

                Color pixel = newBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);

                int colVal = (pixel.R + pixel.G + pixel.B);

                if (lastCol == 1) lastCol = (pixel.R + pixel.G + pixel.B);

                int diff;
                diff = colVal - lastCol;

                //if (colVal > lastCol) { diff = colVal - lastCol; } else { diff = lastCol - colVal; }


                if (diff > 50)
                {
                    roiCount = true;
                    countEnd = x;
                    adjusted.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red);
                    lastCol = colVal;
                    //count++;                  
                }
                else if (diff < -50)
                {
                    //roiCount = true;
                    countStart = x;
                    adjusted.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Blue);
                    lastCol = colVal;

                }
                if (roiCount)
                {

                    for (int i = countStart; i < countEnd; i++)
                    {
                        adjusted.SetPixel(i, y, Color.Green);
                    }
                    int roiCenter = (countStart + countEnd) / 2;
                    //int roiYTest = y + 1;
                    Color roiCenterPixel = newBitmap.GetPixel(roiCenter, y);

                    int colRoiCenterPixel = roiCenterPixel.R + roiCenterPixel.G + roiCenterPixel.B;
                    Color PixelRoi = newBitmap.GetPixel(roiCenter, y + 1);
                    int colRoi = (PixelRoi.R + PixelRoi.G + PixelRoi.B);
                    int diffRoi = colRoiCenterPixel - colRoi;
                    if (diffRoi < -50 || diffRoi > 50)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    roiCount = false;
                    //count++;
                }
            }


}
    label17.Text = Convert.ToString(count); pictureBox1.Image = nB;
```

Additionlly, it turns the color of the rois into green. The counting routine works properly, but as I said, uses the original image. How can I "tell" the counting routine to use the adjusted image? How can I write the modifications to the original image?

Thanks for any help.

Timo

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell - you're not showing us the code for `// COUNTING ROUTINE`, so we can't know which bitmap the counting routine is working on. I'd expect that you need to use the contrast-adjusted image as

```
Bitmap adjusted = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
```

and then perform everything you do in `// COUNTING ROUTINE` on `adjusted`.

---

After you edited the question it is clear from the code that you're working on `newBitmap` (which is the loaded bitmap - the source of your contrast change) instead of the contrast changed bitmap. You should change `newBitmap` in all places where you want to use the contract adjusted bitmap to `adjusted`, which is declared and set as shown above in my answer.

Comment: I tried it and it works. I've wrote a lot of "Spaghetti Code" inside of the Routine and I thought it might me a little bit distractive to mention it.

Comment: By the way, the equivalent of *I tried it and it works* on StackOverflow is to upvote and/or accept the answer ;-)